# Testing if logged-in users see unpublished questions

Tags: python, django, testing

EDIT

---

Here is my test:

```
def test_admin_sees_unpublished_questions(self):
    """
    Logged-in admin users see unpublished questions on the index page.
    """
    # create admin user and log her in
    password = 'password'
    my_admin = User.objects.create_superuser('myuser', 'myemail@test.com', password)
    user = authenticate(username="myuser", password="password")
    if user is not None:
        print(user.username)
    else:
        print('Not found!')
    self.client.login(username=my_admin.username, password=password)
    #create future question and check she can see it
    create_question(question_text="Unpublished question.", days=5)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertContains('Please review these unpublished questions:')
    self.assertEqual(response.context["user"], user)
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        response.context['unpublished_question_list'],
        ['<Question: Unpublished question.>']
    )
```

It's a bit messy. There are a few lines checking if there is a user in context which all appear to show response.context["user"] is there.

Here is my view:

```py
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return the last five published questions (not including those set to be
        published in the future).
        """

        queryset = Question.objects.filter(
                        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
                    ).exclude(
                        #question without choices
                        choice=None
                    ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Override get_context_data to add another variable to the context.
        """
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['unpublished_question_list'] = Question.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=timezone.now())
        print(context)
        return context
```

I am writing tests for the django polls app tutorial.

I want to write a test which which logs in a user, creates an instance of the question model with a publish date in the future, and ensures that this logged in user can see this question.

I've tried using

```py
self.assertContains('Please review these unpublished questions: ')
```

in the test method because my template looks like this:

```html
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Hello, {{ user.username }}. Please review these unpublished questions: </p>
        {% if unpublished_question_list %} etc
```

but even though

```py
self.assertEqual(response.context["user"], user)
```

passes testing after

```py
self.client.login(username=my_admin.username, password=password)
```

my template doesn't seem to be rendering properly to the test client.

Some help would be much appreciated!

AssertionError: False is not true : Couldn't find 'Please review these unpublished questions: ' in response

Comment: Please post your full test code, and the code for the view it is testing. You probably also want to inspect the response in your debugger to see what it does contain.